# Is CAS auth protocol deprecated?

Tags: cas

I see that many tools around authentication do not support integration with CAS. (e.g. AWS Cognito)
Is CAS deprecated for new projects? I'm deciding if I should support CAS IdP for my new SaaS project or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, CAS authentication protocol is not deprecated. CAS authentication protocol is still active based on **https://apereo.github.io/cas/development/protocol/CAS-Protocol-Specification.html**. Most CAS IdPs such as Apereo's CAS Server support other protocols such as SAML and OAuth2. I would adopt these authentication protocols before the CAS authentication protocol.

My 2 cents.